# Need to figure out how convert one char value at a time in an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, rot13

I have already written the code to take in a user's String values into an array. I also wrote the code on printing those back out.

The problem I'm having is understanding how to give method `charConvert()` a char value from the available string array, and have it convert that character, and then replace the character in the string array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class zrwilliams_ROT13Arrays {
    private static Scanner get = new Scanner ( System.in );

    public static void main ( String args[] ){

        String[] sentences = new String[5];
        getSentences ( sentences );
        displayOriginal ( sentences );

        charConvert( );

        for ( char temp = 'A'; temp <= 'Z'; temp++ ) {
            System.out.printf ( "%c converts to %c\n", temp, charConvert(temp));
        }

    }
    /**
     * getSentences
     *
     * This method allows the user to enter text into each of the
     * element of the String array that it receives.
     *
     * @param sentences An array of String[] data
     * @return None
     */
    public static void getSentences ( String[] sent ) {

        System.out.println ( "Enter your 5 sentences below: " );
        System.out.print ( "\n" );

        int a = 1;

        for ( int x = 0 ; x < sent.length; x++ ) {


            System.out.printf ( "Sentence %d> ", a );
            sent[x] = get.nextLine();
            a = a + 1;

        }
    }
    /**
     * displayOriginal
     *
     * This method displays all of the elements of the array of
     * String data that it receives, line by line (element by element).
     *
     * @param sentences An array of String[] data
     * @return None
     */
    public static void displayOriginal ( String[] sent ) {

        System.out.print ( "\nThe original text: \n" );

        for ( int x = 0; x < sent.length; x++ ) {
            System.out.println ( sent[x] );
        }
    }
    /**
     * charConvert
     d     *
     * This method will take one char value as a parameter and convert
     * it to its appropriate ROT13 equivalent. The return value will be the
     * new ROT13 char equivalent.
     *
     * This method will not do any output.
     *
     * @param toConvert A character to convert as a char
     * @return The new ROT13 equivalent value as a char
     */
    public static void charConvert ( String[] sent  ) {

    }
    /**
     * convertSentence
     *
     * This method will do the actual conversion of a String of data to its
     * ROT13 equivalent in 5-character chunks of data. It should call on
     * the charConvert() method to do the actual character conversion for each
     * individual character. In other words, individual character conversion
     * should not happen within this method.
     *
     * This method will not do any output.
     *
     * @param sentence A String variable to convert
     * @return The 5-characters in a group ROT13 result as a String
     */
    public static void convertSentence ( String[] sent ) {

    }
    /**
     * displayROT13
     *
     * This method will display in ROT13 format all of the elements of the
     * array of String data that it receives . It will need to call on the
     * method convertSentence() to convert each string before it displays it.
     * Note that the original array should not be modified with ROT13 data.
     *
     * @param sentences An array of String[] data
     * @return None
     */
    public static void displayROT13 ( String[] sent ) {

    }
    /**
     * displayCombinedROT13
     *
     * This method takes an array of String data and combines all of the Strings
     * into a single String that is then processed by the convertSentence()
     * method. The method should essentially display the same results as the
     * displayROT13() method, except that there won't be separate lines of
     * output but rather one large result instead.
     *
     * @param sentences An array of String[] data
     * @return None
     */
    public static void displayCombinedROT13 ( String[] sent ) {

    }
}
```

Comment: what's the issue ?

Comment: i can't figure out how to send one character value from a string to a method at a time. I dont need code written for me. Just an explanation on how to do it

Comment: [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) might be quite helpful. In general: you first need to retrieve the value from the array and use it as parameter for the method (not explained in that tutorial, but still you should give it a read). A rather generic example would look like this: `some_method(array[index]);` calls `some_method` with the array-element at the specified index.

Comment: Try to convert it to charArray an choose the character of you need retun it char or string , some thing like this maybe help you: `String testString = "This Is Test";
  char[] stringToCharArray = testString.toCharArray();
 
  for (char output : stringToCharArray) {
   System.out.println(output);
  }`

Comment: Thanks Paul! now if i wanted to cycle through all of the values in the array, should i just create a for loop so it hits every one?